# How do I display more rows of a Dataframe in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Currently my notebook is showing rows like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpFbF.jpg). However, I see other people notebooks showing like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYnT3.jpg), despite of mine having the max rows set to 60.

What do I need to do to make Jupyter Notebook display more rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will not work on jupiter!!!

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
data1.sex
```

if you want to see all rows :

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
data1.sex
```

If you just want to see 60 rows:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 60)
data1.sex.head(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help

```
pandas.set_option("display.max_rows", max_rows, "display.max_columns", max_cols)
```